# Create variable using this pointer and method arguments at compile time and use this variable as argument to a constexpr method

Tags: c++, class, templates, constexpr, compile-time

Suppose that you have a scenario like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct A {
    std::array<T, N> arr;
    constexpr A(std::initializer_list<T> a) {
        std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), arr.begin());
    }
    constexpr A(auto rhs) {
        std::copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), arr.begin());
    }
    constexpr std::size_t countLeadingZeros(const auto& arr) const {
        std::size_t count = 0;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            if (arr[i] == 0) { count++; }
        }
        return count;
    }
    constexpr auto operator+(A rhs) const {
        std::array<T, N> result_array;
        result_array.fill(T{0});
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            result_array[i] = arr[i] + rhs.arr[i];
        }
        constexpr std::size_t zeros = countLeadingZeros(result_array);
        std::array<T, zeros> arr;

        return A(arr);
    }
};

template<typename ... T>
A(T...) -> A<std::common_type_t<T...>, sizeof...(T)>;

int main() {
    constexpr A a{1, 2, 3}; 
    constexpr A b{4, 5, 6};
    constexpr A c = a + b;
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/q9T9WxxeY

I want to be able to use zeros in a compile time context, but because `result_array` is not constexpr this fails. My question is: Is it a way to create `result_array` at compile time for use it as an argument to constexpr method `countLeadingZeros`?

The compiler error messages are:

```
error: constexpr variable 'zeros' must be initialized by a constant expression

constexpr std::size_t zeros = countLeadingZeros(result_array);

note: in instantiation of member function 'A<int, 3>::operator+' requested here

constexpr A c = a + b;

note: implicit use of 'this' pointer is only allowed within the evaluation of a call to a 'constexpr' member function

constexpr std::size_t zeros = countLeadingZeros(result_array);
```

Comment: `result_array` depends on parameter `rhs` and `this` which aren't/cannot be constexpr. so no, as-is. you would need something like `constexpr A c = Sum<a, b>();` or extra step: `constexpr A c = take<countLeadingZeros(a + b)>(a + b);`

Comment: Think about what the `constexpr`  annotation does on a function. It **allows** a function to be executed at compile time, but it doesn't **force** it. This means your `operator+` can also run at runtime, which means you pass a runtime value to `countLeadingZeros`, making it run at runtime as well.

Comment: Ok, thank you! That was my approach, but I wanted to know if it can be done without passing a and b to an auto template parameter. Now it is clear to me, thank you again! :) @Jarod42

Comment: Yes, I know that @Timo . But I thought that it is a workaround for that. Thank you! :)

Comment: @JeJo Can you show me an example because I don't get it.